# Unexplained presentation variance

Tags: discussion, bug, design

If you come to META and click 'Questions|Newest', you get a presentation like this...

[image]

3 rows, 1 column

but if you click the "Travel" logo, it changes to the "Questions|Active" sort and the presentation goes to this...

[image]

1 row, 3 columns

Does this seem out of whack to anybody else?  Or alternatively, is there a rationale for changing the page layout for the two views?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess, the questions page shows an overview of the question, which makes the rows higher while the main page which shows nothing but the title, which makes the row narrower.

The main page is just an overview, it needs to be compact to show as much rows as possible, while the questions page is mainly for those who intend to answer hence showing more details about each question (the overview).